# Can you create a new iCloud account / Apple ID with the email address from a deleted account?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

(I'm equating iCloud account and Apple ID below ... I hope that makes sense)

1. If I create an iCloud account / Apple ID with a given email address "foo@bar.baz",
2. And then I delete that account,
3. Can I subsequently create a new account using the same email
   address?

I believe the answer is “no.” I created an iCloud account using my business email address. I believe (not 100% certain) that I subsequently deleted that account.

I recently got a new iPhone from work. They prefer I use an iCloud account tied to my business email address.

I tried using the “forgot password flow” but got the error: "This Apple ID is either not valid or not supported."

I tried creating a new account with my business email address but got the error: "This email is not available. Choose a different address."

Which leads me to believe an email address cannot be re-used for an iCloud account.

Comment: Worth noting you can create an iCloud account / Apple ID using the "+" trick supported by Gmail (and others?). E.g., me+icloud@company.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which leads me to believe an email address cannot be re-used for an iCloud account

#### Your email address will be permanently locked out.

You are correct in that belief.  And specific to your situation with a business account (assuming a custom domain name), it can never be reused even if domain ownership changes.

Per the [Apple ID FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208504)

> **Can I use the primary email address for my deleted Apple ID account to create a new Apple ID or with another existing Apple ID account?**
>
> No, once your Apple ID is deleted, you can't use the email address that you used with it to create a new Apple ID. In addition, you can't use that email address with another existing Apple ID except as a rescue email. Also, if your primary Apple ID email address is with a Custom Email Domain, it can never be reused to create an Apple ID after your Apple ID is deleted, even if the domain ownership changes.